# Javascript to match string with pattern and insert some text in the matched string

Tags: javascript, regex

input:

```
 blah blah blah text blah <a href="/abcblah/blah">some random text</a> text blah blah random
```

**action:** match all the instances of the href tags that has a relative link, then insert the host url.
output:

```
blah blah blah text blah <a href="http://www.rooturl.com/abcblah/blah">some random text</a> text blah blah random
```

I am wondering how to do this quickly and cleanly in javascript, need help from regex experts..Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: Could you please show your attempt?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you wan to do this? if you access anchor dom element href attributes it returns it with hostname no matter what.

Comment: @nanshi why do you think you have to do this? What is your end goal?

Comment: @raam86, html is not just for web nowadays, you can open it in a webcontrol on ios or android too. when you run into a relative link, basically it's a dead link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex based solution should work for you:

```
str = 'blah blah text blah <a href="/abcblah/blah">some random text</a> text blah random';
repl = str.replace(/(href=['"](?!https?:))\/?/g, "$1http://www.rooturl.com/");
console.log(repl);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/G5F0vF

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Updated version: rep = str.replace(/(href=['"](?!((https?:)|(mailto:)|(tel:))))/g, "$1"+hostname); -- this turned out to be complex and i am worried that i may miss some valid tags :)

Comment: my final version: rep= str.replace(/(href=['"])(\/)/g, "$1"+hostname+"$2") -- haven't figure out anything that i may miss so far.